# Yii import an external file

Tags: php, yii

```
cssimageslangs en
site.phpprotected
controllermodelview
```

This is my folder structure. I want to import this site.php file in a controller SiteController. I tried `Yii::import('langs.en.site', true);` , tried alias in main config. But nothing worked. Any other way ?

code in site.php

```
define('EnterEmail', 'Email cannot be blank.');
define('EmailExists', 'The email you entered is already registered.');
define('EmailNotRegistered', 'This email ID is not registered with us.');
..............
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't just use Yii::t() and messages? Its way easier. 
You need to define alias langs:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('langs','/home/../../langs/');
```

Then in your import in config you can use it:

```
'import'=>array('langs.en.*')
```

Look at Yii::t() please, its way better.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. I am new to Yii. Since langs is a folder could you please explain where to setPathofAlias.

Comment: `Yii::setPathOfAlias('langs',Yii::app()->basePath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'langs'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);` try like this.

Answer (score 0):

Hope all these are just Defined and can be given in params

- protected

  - config

    - params.php

params.php

```
return array(
    'EnterEmail' => 'Email cannot be blank.',
    'EmailExists' => 'The email you entered is already registered.',
    'EmailNotRegistered' => 'This email ID is not registered with us.',
   .....
);
```

which would be included in main.php from config like this

```
 'params' => require(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'params.php' ),
```

it can be easily accessed

Comment: I cant just set it in params. Since these messages are multi-lingual.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your path with **webroot**:

```
Yii::import('webroot.langs.en.site');
$site = new Site;
```

For more paths see this page:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.namespace#root-alias

Asides that, it is way, way more better to user the build in functions for translations ([link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n#translation)). The key is to use Yii::t like this:

```
Yii::t('app', 'This is my text to be translated');
```

When done use **Yiic** to generate language files wich you can adjust:

```
protected/yiic message protected/messages/config.php
```